# how to align strings in python without creating a table

Tags: python, pretty-print

I have a problem. I'm trying to print a serie of lists in python to have it with a vertical align. My code is:

```
def show():
    book = "data.txt"
    f = open(book,'r')
    line = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    x=0
    z = ''
    l = []
    x = []
    i = 0
    starting = '{:>4}  {:>15}  {:>15}'.format('Name', "Gender", "Year")
    print(starting)
    for p in line:
        p = p.replace(',',' ')
        x = p.index(' ')
        name = p[0:x]
        a = p.index('e 1')
        gender = p[x:a+1]
        year = p[(a+2):]
        if len(name) == 3:
            line_new = '{:>2}  {:>15}  {:>15}'.format(name, gender, year)
        else:
            line_new = '{:>5}  {:>15}  {:>15}'.format(name, gender, year)
        print(line_new)
```

The problem is that I'm trying to have something like:

[image]
I want to put all the names of the left (and I don't have problems) then, under Gender, I want to create an equal list of Genders all on the same vertical and same thing for year

Comment: Well, ask yourself a question - what does it mean to align text? How can that be achieved?

Comment: What output do you get? And what does the contents of your file look like?

Comment: Not so easy to express it here. I'll try to put a photo of my output

Comment: use the word widths, but use tabs `line_new = '{:>5}\t{:>15}\t{:>15}'.format(name, gender, year)`

Comment: ok. Best @Calpratt. Sorry for the stupid question

Comment: 1. find maximum width for each column 2. Use the calculated widths: `'{name:>{name_width}} {gender:>6} {year:>4}'.format(**vars())`

Comment: @pp94 No apologies required, and it's not a dumb question. Its only a dumb question if you don't learn anything from it!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try this:

```
import itertools
with open("data.txt") as data:
    pep =  [line.strip().split(',') for line in data]
    widths = [len(max(r, key=len)) for r in itertools.izip_longest(*pep, fillvalue="")]

    print "%-{0}%s%-{1}%s%-{2}%s".format(widths[0], widths[1], widths[2])\
    %("Name", "Gender", "Year")

    print "\n".join(["%-{0}%s%-{1}%s%-{2}%s".format(widths[0], widths[1], widths[2])\
    %(attr[0], attr[1], attr[2]) for attr in pep])
```